# Function that gets slice of strings and extracts them as arguments to shell command in Rust

Tags: ubuntu, rust

I'm trying to automate some installs using `std::process::Command`. For example, I want to write a "wrapper" function for Ubuntu's `apt-get install`. This command can take some optional flags like `--no-install-recommends` etc. How can I use these options if I pass them as a slice to the function? So I would like to have something like that:

```rust
fn apt_install(package_name: &str, options: &[&str]) {
    let mut c = Command::new("apt-get")
        .arg("install")
        // Flags here, as many as specified in 'options' argument
        .spawn()
        .expect(format!("Failed to install {}", package_name).as_str());
    c.wait().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Like [`arg()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) there's also [`args()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Command::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args):

```rust
fn apt_install(package_name: &str, options: &[&str]) {
    let mut c = Command::new("apt-get")
        .arg("install")
        .args(options)
        .spawn()
        .expect(format!("Failed to install {}", package_name).as_str());
    c.wait().unwrap();
}
```